# Mongo Spark Connector: MongoTypeConversionException Cannot cast DATE_TIME into a NullType

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read from a mongo source and apply some transformation on it. But when I try to apply any transformation or even do a `df.count()`. I get the following error.

```
MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast DATE_TIME into a NullType
```

So I understand a column has a mixed data type, in this case, `NULL` and `TIMESTAMP`. I am using a `mongo-spark-connector_2.11` version `2.2.1` which says **ConflictTypes** has a base type as **StringType**.

So a workaround is to pass schema, column names and types so that the connector won't infer the types itself. But how do I pass schema?

Here's my Java code to read from mongo

```
DataFrameReader x = ss.read().format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").options("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "<mongo_uri>");
Dataset<Row> = x.load();
```

`ss` is SparkSession object.

Answer (score 2):

Please import Java SQL Date, it will resolve the issue.

```
import java.sql.Date;
//import java.util.Date;
```

Error Type:

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.spark.exceptions.MongoTypeConversionException: Cannot cast DATE_TIME into a StructType(StructField(date,IntegerType,false), S
```

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB Connector for Spark default use 1000 sample of your every field to build its schema, so if one field **contain different datatype such as Null datatype and datetime datatype**, and MongoDB Connector for Spark can possiblely not sample the datetime data and take that filed as a Null datatype. At least, when your use count method, connector will try to load data from mongodb to speifiy data type in spark dataframe, and cause this error: "MongoTypeConversionException Cannot cast DATE_TIME into a NullType"

**The Solution:**

**Add the sample data of MongoDB Connector for Spark to build a correct schema.** For example, in pyspark:

```
df = session.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option('sampleSize', 50000).load()
```

Comment: Can you explain how increasing the sample number will solve this problem? Wouldn't you still be reading in null fields?

Comment: @Ted Increasing the sample will increase the possibility for Spark to build a correct schema significantly. if Spark know one field contain different datatype such as Null datatype and datetime datatype, it will build a suitable column type for that field in dataframe, such as string.

Answer (score 0):

I used import java.sql.Timestamp as my mongo field had Timestamp and everything worked fine.